# Symfony 2 redirect route

Tags: symfony, routes

I have the following route that works via a get:

```
CanopyAbcBundle_crud_success:
  pattern:  /crud/success/
  defaults: { _controller: CanopyAbcBundle:Crud:success }
  requirements:
    _method:  GET
```

Where Canopy is the namespace, the bundle is AbcBundle, controller Crud, action is success.

The following fails:

```
return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('crud_success'));

Unable to generate a URL for the named route "crud_success" as such route does not exist.
500 Internal Server Error - RouteNotFoundException
```

How can I redirect with generateUrl()?

Comment: you should be use:    return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('CanopyAbcBundle_crud_success'));

Answer (score 23):

Clear your cache using `php app/console cache:clear`

```php
return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('CanopyAbcBundle_crud_success'));
```

If parameters are required pass like this:

```php
return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('CanopyAbcBundle_crud_success', array('param1' => $param1)), 301);
```

Answer (score 6):

The first line of your YAML is the route name that should be used with the router component. You're trying to generate a URL for the wrong route name, yours is `CanopyAbcBundle_crud_success`, not `crud_success`.
Also, `generateUrl()` method does what it says: it generates a URL from route name and parameters (it they are passed). To return a 403 redirect response, you could either use `$this->redirect($this->generateUrl('CanopyAbcBundle_crud_success'))` which is built into the `Controller` base class, or you could return an instance of `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse` like this:

> ```
> public function yourAction()
> {
>     return new RedirectResponse($this->generateUrl('CanopyAbcBundle_crud_success'));
> }
> ```